# Extracting the URL file name in CGI bash script

Tags: bash

I have two CGI files:

script1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<form action="/cgi-bin/gene-to-structure/NM_002014-
NP_002005.1/script5.sh" method="GET">"
echo "<p><input type="checkbox" name="residue" value="V---M">                  
<br></p>"
echo "<p><input type="checkbox" name="residue" value="K---N">                   
<br></p>"
echo "<input type="submit" value="Submit">"
echo "</form>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

In the above script on clicking the "submit" button I am taken to "script5.sh" CGI script. I want to retrieve the "file name" (script1.sh) of the file from which after clicking the "submit" button I came to "script5.sh". Can you please let me know how it can be done?

So, I want to do this in "script5.sh":

Script5.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo "The file name of the file is "script1.sh"".
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: The info on caller can be found in [Referer HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

Comment: Thanks much! But, can you please tell me how to do it on my example above?

Comment: OK, I got it, I took the file name from "HTTP_REFERER" of the environment variable. Thanks.